# youtube-dl does not download auto-generated subtitles

Tags: flags, youtube-dl, playlist, subtitle

I am trying to download a playlist of videos, all of them with auto-generated subtitles but when I insert the flag `--write-sub`/`--write-auto-sub` it says that de videos do not have subtitles. I usually use the same code to download videos with subtitles, which is simple and usually does the job. However with the auto-generated subtitles does not work:

```
youtube-dl -f best --yes-playlist --output '%(title)s.%(ext)s' --write-auto-sub 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7MNX_UD7vY&list=PLIhvC56v63IJVXv0GJcl9vO5Z6znCVb1P
```

I also tried to add `--sub-lang en` with no results.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with youtube-dl for a month or so.
As of now (Dec 26, 2020), a fix is already merged to master https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/pull/27388 and most probably will be available in the next version ( > 2020.12.22)